# How to print bit field with boost format

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost::format to print out a structure. However, the boost::format seems having trouble to handle "bit field", see the following example:

```
// Linux: g++ test.cc -lboost_system
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

struct bits_t {
    unsigned int io: 1;
    unsigned int co;
};

int main(void) {

    using std::cout;
    using boost::format;

    bits_t b; b.io = 1; b.co = 2;

    printf("io = %d \n", b.io); // Okay
    cout << format("co = %d \n") % b.co;  // Okay
    // cout << format("io = %d \n") % b.io;  // Not Okay
    return 0;

}
```

Notice the second `cout` which I commented out, it tries to print out the bit field as `printf` does, but compiler complains:

```
`error: cannot bind bitfield ‘b.bits_t::io’ to ‘unsigned int&’
```

I wonder what did I miss? Thanks

Comment: Cast it to `int` before printing, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I came across a similar issue with Boost Log. It's `operator <<` also takes argument by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `boost::format` takes arguments by const reference (not a copy), and a reference can not be bound to a bitfield.

You can solve this by converting the value to a temporary integer.  One *succinct* way would be to apply the unary `operator +`.

```
 cout << format("io = %d \n") % +b.io;  // NOW Okay
```